# Explosions on a chessboard

Tags: code-golf, chess

[Atomic chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_chess) is a (very fun)
variant of chess in which every capture causes an "explosion," destroying the
captured piece, the piece doing the capturing, and all non-pawns in a 1-square
radius. The goal of this challenge is not to play an entire game of atomic
chess, but simply to simulate what happens when a certain move is made.

Disclaimer: Explosion sound effects not included.

### Input

Board position will be given in [Forsyth-Edwards
Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)
(commonly known as FEN), but with only the first field. For example, an input
of:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

represents the starting position:

[image: Chess starting position.]

This must be taken as a string or your language's equivalent. It is guaranteed
to be valid; for example, you don't have to care if there are ten kings, or if
there is no king at all.

You will also be given the move that you are to simulate, which is represented
as two square names: the square on which the piece to be moved is, and the
square it is moving to. For example, moving the king's pawn two spaces forwards
on the above picture would be represented as:

```
e2e4
```

This must also be taken as a string. The move will always be valid, and you do
not need to support [castling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling). You do
need to support [*en passant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant), which
will be explained in further detail in the next section.

### Output

The output of your program should be in the same partial-FEN notation as the
input, with the specified move made (and any pieces exploded if necessary).

The exact rules for explosions are—when a piece is captured:

- Remove the piece being captured (this will always be the piece on the second
  square named in the input, except for when the capture is an *en passant*).
- Remove the piece that is doing the capturing (this will always be the piece
  on the first square named in the input).
- Remove every piece that is:

  - located on one of the 8 squares surrounding the one where the capture took
    place (for *en passant*, this is the square that the capturing pawn would
    be on, if it didn't explode).
  - not a pawn.

Quick overview of *en passant* rules, for those who are unfamiliar: if a pawn
moves two spaces forwards from its starting rank, and there is a pawn that
could have captured it if it only moved one square forward, it may capture it
anyway, but only on the subsequent move. This capture is said to be done "*in
passing*" (or in French: "*en passant*").

### Test cases

In the pictures, the green arrows represet the move about to be made, and the
green circles represents pieces that are exploded.

Input: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR`, `g1f3`
Output: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/5N2/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKB1R`
[image: Test case 1.]

---

Input: `3kBb1r/pp5p/3p4/4pn2/P7/1P2P1pP/2rP1P2/R1B3RK`, `f2g3`
Output: `3kBb1r/pp5p/3p4/4pn2/P7/1P2P2P/2rP4/R1B3RK`
[image: Test case 2.]
*(stolen from http://en.lichess.org/ocoSfS5I/white#36)*

---

Input: `rnbqk1nr/1pp5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1PQ1N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R`, `f3b7`
Output: `3qk1nr/2p5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1P2N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R`
[image: Test case 3.]
*(stolen from http://en.lichess.org/NCUnA6LV/white#14)*

---

Input: `rnbqk2r/pp2p2p/2p3pb/3pP3/5P2/2N5/PPPP2P1/R1BQKB1R`, `e5d6`
Output: `rnbqk2r/pp2p2p/2p3pb/8/5P2/2N5/PPPP2P1/R1BQKB1R`
[image: Test case 4.]
*(stolen from http://en.lichess.org/AvgU4Skq/white#16; this wasn't the actual
move, but I couldn't be bothered to find an atomic game that actually had en
passant :P)*

---

Input: `5r2/2k5/p1B5/1pP1p3/1P4P1/3P4/P7/1K3R1q`, `c6h1`
Output: `5r2/2k5/p7/1pP1p3/1P4P1/3P4/P7/1K3R2`
[image: Test case 5.]
*(stolen from http://en.lichess.org/l77efXEb/white#58)*

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: So... taking a piece with your king is a bad idea?

Comment: @mbomb007 You are not allowed to take pieces with your king. :P

Comment: I might be mistaken, but how are we supposed to know if the en passant capture is possible? In your example the last move is denoted by the empty green square, so the black pawned can be captured en passant. But this information is not contained in the inputs we are given, so it is possible to have the exact same board but where the en passant capture is not possible, because the last move was not a two spaces forward move.

Comment: @Fatalize "*The move will always be valid*" - from the "Input" section.

Comment: Complete program or function?

Comment: @edc65 http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/3808

Comment: As I submitted a function, happy to use the default. Asking because you explicitly said "your program..."

Comment: +1 for "Explosion sound effects not included"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 305 <s>310 321</s>

As a function with 2 real parameters (and a lot more with default values, used as a quick and dirty way to define locals)

Test running the snippet below (being EcmaScript 6, Firefox only)

```js
F=(g,m,b=[...g.replace(/\d/g,c=>'0'.repeat(c))],P=p=>p=='p'|p=='P',n=parseInt(m,32),
  s=n>>5&31,u=n>>15,x=b[y=u+62-(n>>10&31)*9])=>(
  b[b[y]=0,z=s+62-(n&31)*9]<1&!(s!=u&P(x))?b[z]=x:
  [-1,1,8,9,10,-8,-9,-10].map(i=>b[i+=z]>'/'&&!P(b[i])?b[i]=0:0,b[b[z]<1?z>y?z-9:z+9:z]=0),
  b.join('').replace(/0+/g,x=>x.length)
)

//TEST
out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

test=[
 ['rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR', 'g1f3'
  ,'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/5N2/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKB1R']
,['3kBb1r/pp5p/3p4/4pn2/P7/1P2P1pP/2rP1P2/R1B3RK', 'f2g3'
  ,'3kBb1r/pp5p/3p4/4pn2/P7/1P2P2P/2rP4/R1B3RK']  
,['rnbqk1nr/1pp5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1PQ1N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R', 'f3b7'
  ,'3qk1nr/2p5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1P2N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R']
,['rnbqk2r/pp2p2p/2p3pb/3pP3/5P2/2N5/PPPP2P1/R1BQKB1R', 'e5d6'
  ,'rnbqk2r/pp2p2p/2p3pb/8/5P2/2N5/PPPP2P1/R1BQKB1R']
,['5r2/2k5/p1B5/1pP1p3/1P4P1/3P4/P7/1K3R1q', 'c6h1'
  ,'5r2/2k5/p7/1pP1p3/1P4P1/3P4/P7/1K3R2']
]

test.forEach(t=>( 
  r=F(t[0],t[1]), 
  out('Test '+(r==t[2]?'Ok':'Fail!')+'  '+t[0]+' move '+t[1]
     +'\nResult   '+r+'\nExpected '+t[2]+'\n')))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

**Ungolfed**

```js
B=(b,m)=>{
  P=p=>p=='p'|p=='P'
  m=parseInt(m,32) 
  r=m&31 // arrival row
  s=(m/32&31)-10 // arrival column
  z=s+(8-r)*9 // arrival position
  t=m/32/32&31 // start row
  u=(m/32/32/32&31)-10 // start column
  y=u+(8-t)*9 // start position
  b=[...b.replace(/\d/g,c=>'0'.repeat(c))] // board to array, empty squares as 0
  x=b[y] // moving piece
  b[y]=0 
  C=s!=u&P(x) // pawn capture
  if (b[z]<1 && !C)
  {  // no capture
    b[z]=x
  }
  else
  {
    // capture and boom!
    if (b[z]<1) // arrival empty: en passant
      b[z>y?z-9:z+9]=0;
    else
      b[z]=0;
    // zero to nearest 8 squares
    [-1,1,8,9,10,-8,-9,-10].forEach(i=>b[i+=z]>'/'&&!P(b[i])?b[i]=0:0)
  }
  return b.join('').replace(/0+/g,x=>x.length)
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot simpler than my solution... Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 240 bytes

```apl
e←' '@(p/⍨~(x←∊∘'Pp')(b←↑⊃¨,/¨{⍵∊⎕D:' '/⍨⍎⍵⋄⍵}¨¨'/'(≠⊆⊢)⎕)[p←p/⍨{∧/⍵∊⍳8}¨p←(⊃⌽c←{(9-⍎⊃⌽⍵),⎕A⍳⊃⍵}¨↓2 2⍴1⎕C⎕)∘+¨,∘.,⍨2-⍳3])
1↓⊃,/{'/',⊃,/{' '∊⍵:⍕≢⍵⋄⍵}¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}¨↓{(x⊃n)∧(≠/⊃¨⌽¨c)∧' '=⊃⌽n←b[c]:e' '@((⊃c)+0,1↓⊃-⍨/c)⊢b⋄' '∊n:(⌽n)@c⊢b⋄e' '@c⊢b}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHBTttAEIbvforc1hZOh92NgUaqRN3eIkWOr4gDdpxUCnKXqAcqix5KlQZTo1YVEkeUC75Tjr3kUfZF0n@MqSrqlezZ2fn/@WZ9ZI67449Hx@@n3ez0Q5aPs/HGLr9ONpldfBcdse8aslX9yT3F3i5Lu7wRkRGem/B@8cOW5@vap3Vd2OqBz6@u3/ahY5Gtrjh5@QXvs3W9rgUJ117c2nJhy5WHUu/AwKbpUNjlHbUe1f0e6vnIhb/99jtFWLgvu@zYJFDo@TB4jVrONA3s4qfqKFv9kjh5w/ag3QIePi989FAwuNeHniNRCplPBZD8NuqIpvdD31bX9mL1LzrH5Wc4SF9hAPrbr8C9lOc5Gt25zQFfB/jWdco5eL56BM4xQXKQHvaz5lJ5rtTb2vZbEoDVBEm5StD0ESXvuyz09tM23Uibzdk2/6TNxBFTOdHCEfM8OZkl@ZxM@9Beu6L2oXgYjgbhMBYOboZ/rnCgn6gp6/UsTCSrA0Pa9KhnckXRLslIRdJEpOYRQoplqOPBMwed7D4RSBBImJBRxiCgwCiSyTAg2EQjOQSOxGIcGcpBKJ/hZMF458lMMY/CImW0ScAVaQpAoeDHI8GTbUb/26Q77yRsgjmKZ6CRYQAuTKIxUQ8yHfWa8QY6lifiDw)

A full program which takes the FEN first, and the move second.

### Explanation

**First Line: Explode. Function**

```apl
e←' '@(p/⍨~(x←∊∘'Pp')(b←↑⊃¨,/¨{⍵∊⎕D:' '/⍨⍎⍵⋄⍵}¨¨'/'(≠⊆⊢)⎕)[p←p/⍨{∧/⍵∊⍳8}¨p←(⊃⌽c←{(9-⍎⊃⌽⍵),⎕A⍳⊃⍵}¨↓2 2⍴1⎕C⎕)∘+¨,∘.,⍨2-⍳3])
```

`1⎕C⎕` capitalize the first input

`↓2 2⍴` cut into halves

`{(9-⍎⊃⌽⍵),⎕A⍳⊃⍵}¨` apply the following to each square name:
         `,⎕A⍳⊃⍵` get position of first char in the alphabet(column)
`(9-⍎⊃⌽⍵)`        get 9-int(second char) (row number)

`c←` store that in c

`⊃⌽` take the last element

`∘+¨` and add that to:

`,∘.,⍨2-⍳3` the cartesian product of (-1,0,1), getting the von neumann neighborhood

`p←` assign the explosion indices to p

`p←p/⍨{∧/⍵∊⍳8}¨` remove the ones outside the board, and reassign to p

`(...)[...]` and index into the following:

`'/'(≠⊆⊢)⎕` split the second input on slashes

`⊃¨,/¨{⍵∊⎕D:' '/⍨⍎⍵⋄⍵}¨¨` convert each digit to the appropriate amount of spaces

`b←↑` and convert it to a matrix, storing in b. This is the chess board.

`x←∊∘'Pp'` store function to check for pawns in x

`p/⍨~(x←∊∘'Pp')` now, remove the points which map to pawns

`' '@` and insert a space at those indices in the right argument.

**Second line: capture calculator**

```apl
1↓⊃,/{'/',⊃,/{' '∊⍵:⍕≢⍵⋄⍵}¨⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵}¨↓{(x⊃n)∧(≠/⊃¨⌽¨c)∧' '=⊃⌽n←b[c]:e' '@((⊃c)+0,1↓⊃-⍨/c)⊢b⋄' '∊n:(⌽n)@c⊢b⋄e' '@c⊢b}0
```

`n←b[c]` assign the starting and ending characters to n

`' '=⊃⌽n←b[c]` If ending square is empty,

`(≠/⊃¨⌽¨c)∧` start column and end column are not equal,

`(x⊃n)∧` and capturing piece is a pawn(en passant):

`0,1↓⊃-⍨/c` get the direction of capture

`(⊃c)+` add that to the start index

`' '@((⊃c)+0,1↓⊃-⍨/c)⊢b` insert a space at that point

`e` and **explode.**

`' '∊n` else, if ending point is a space(no capture):

`(⌽n)@c⊢b⋄` switch the places of the space and the piece

`' '@c⊢b` Otherwise, insert a space at the start and end index(normal capture)

`e` and **explode.**

`¨↓` then, take each row,

`⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵` group it into equal runs

`{' '∊⍵:⍕≢⍵⋄⍵}¨` replace runs of spaces with their length.

`'/',⊃,/` join everything together and prepend a /

`1↓⊃,/` join the rows together and drop the first /.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, (<s>946</s> <s>777</s> 776 chars)

*1 char thanks to @edc65*

Note: Chars counted without test cases put in.

**Code**

```
class E{public static void main(String[]a){String i=a[0];char[]n=a[1].toCharArray();int j,k,z,w,y,u=56-n[3];char q,p,e ='e';char[][]b=new char[8][8];String[]r=i.split("/");for(j=0;j<8;j++){z=0;for(k=0;k<r[j].length();k++){p=r[j].charAt(k);if(Character.isDigit(p)){for(int l=k+z;l<k+z+p-48;l++)b[j][l]=e;z+=p-49;}else b[j][k+z]=p;}}z=n[0]-97;w=56-n[1];y=n[2]-97;p=b[w][z];q=b[u][y];b[w][z]=e;if(q!=e||((p|32)=='p'&&(w-u<0?u-w:w-u)==1&&(z-y<0?y-z:z-y)==1)){if(q!=e)b[u][y]=e;else b[w][y]=e;for(j=y-(y==0?0:1);j<y+(y==8?0:y==7?1:2);j++){for(k=u-(u==0?0:1);k<u+(u==8?0:u==7?1:2);k++)if((b[k][j]|32)!='p')b[k][j]=e;}}else b[u][y]=p;i="";for(j=0;j<8;j++){z=0;for(k=0;k<8;k++){if(b[j][k]==e)z++;else {if(z>0){i+=z;z=0;}i+=b[j][k];}}if(z>0)i+=z;i+=j!=7?"/":"";}System.out.print(i);}}
```

I'm not sure if this solution is optimal, but I'm working on golfing it more, any suggestions are welcome. I can comment all the code too if anyone would like, but I think it's mostly self explanatory, except for the confusing variable enumeration.

**Explanation**

- Unpack the board string into a char matrix
- Calculate the effect of the move
- Repack the board into a string

**Expanded**

```
class ExplosionChess{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        String i=a[0];
        //"rnbqk1nr/1pp5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1PQ1N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R";
        //"f3b7";
        char[]n=a[1].toCharArray();
        int j,k,z,w,y,u=56-n[3];
        char q,p,e ='e';
        char[][]b=new char[8][8];
        String[]r=i.split("/");
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            z=0;
            for(k=0;k<r[j].length();k++){
                p=r[j].charAt(k);
                if(Character.isDigit(p)){
                    for(int l=k+z;l<k+z+p-48;l++)
                        b[j][l]=e;
                    z+=p-49;
                }else 
                    b[j][k+z]=p;
            }
        }
        z=n[0]-97;
        w=56-n[1];
        y=n[2]-97;
        p=b[w][z];
        q=b[u][y];
        b[w][z]=e;
        if(q!=e||((p|32)=='p'&&(w-u<0?u-w:w-u)==1&&(z-y<0?y-z:z-y)==1)){
            if(q!=e)
                b[u][y]=e;
            else
                b[w][y]=e;
            for(j=y-(y==0?0:1);j<y+(y==8?0:y==7?1:2);j++){
                for(k=u-(u==0?0:1);k<u+(u==8?0:u==7?1:2);k++)
                    if((b[k][j]|32)!='p')
                        b[k][j]=e;
            }
        }else 
            b[u][y]=p;
        i="";
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            z=0;
            for(k=0;k<8;k++){
                if(b[j][k]==e)
                    z++;
                else {
                    if(z>0){
                        i+=z;
                        z=0;
                    }
                    i+=b[j][k];
                }
            }
            if(z>0)
                i+=z;
            i+=j!=7?"/":"";
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

**Old**

```
class E{public static void main(String[]a){String m,i="rnbqk1nr/1pp5/p2pp1pp/5p2/1bN5/2P1PQ1N/PP1P1PPP/R1B1KB1R";m="f3b7";char[]n=m.toCharArray();int z,w,y,u=56-n[3];z=n[0]-97;w=56-n[1];y=n[2]-97;char e='e';char[][]b=new char[8][8];String[]r=i.split("/");for(int j=0;j<8;j++){int o=0;for(int k=0;k<r[j].length();k++){char q=r[j].charAt(k);if(Character.isDigit(q)){for(int l=k+o;l<k+o+q-48;l++){b[j][l]=e;}o+=q-49;}else b[j][k+o]=q;}}char q,p=b[w][z];q=b[u][y];b[w][z]=e;if(q==e){if((p|32)=='p'&&(w-u<0?u-w:w-u)==1&&(z-y<0?y-z:z-y)==1){b[w][y]=e;for(int j=y-(y==0?0:1);j<y+(y==8?0:y==7?1:2);j++){for(int k=u-(u==0?0:1);k<u+(u==8?0:u==7?1:2);k++){if((b[k][j]|32)!='p')b[k][j]=e;}}}else{b[u][y]=p;}}else{b[u][y]=e;for(int j=y-(y==0?0:1);j<y+(y==8?0:y==7?1:2);j++){for(int k=u-(u==0?0:1);k<u+(u==8?0:u==7?1:2);k++){if((b[k][j]|32)!='p')b[k][j]=e;}}}i="";for(int j=0;j<8;j++){int x=0;for(int k=0;k<8;k++){if(b[j][k]==e)x++;else{if(x>0){i+=x;x=0;}i+=b[j][k];}}if(x>0)i+=x;i+=j!=7?"/":"";}System.out.println(i);}}
```

Comment: `String m,i="";m="";char[]n=m.toCharArray()` --> `String i=a[0];char[]n=a[1].toCharArray()` is shorter and so you get the parameters from outside (as you *should* anyway)

Comment: Ahh, okay I'll change that, thanks!